# What do は and と stand for here?

Tags: particles

> 家で一人で勉強するよりはと通信制の高校をすすめた。

Does は like summarize the first sentence and と means "from"? Is there a different way to construct that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, よりは is also a set unit of particle as よりも, for examples:

今年の夏は涼しいというよりは寒かった。This summer was cold rather than cool.

その本よりももっと大切なものがあります。There's a more precious thing than that book.

However, when I googled on internet, I found most native writers simply drop “は”from the unit. Or should I say より in itself is a set unit too.

All three units よりは, よりも, and より convey the meaning of “in comparison to”.  Of course, there might be some slight differences in nuance that I’m not aware of.

Now, about the sentence in question “家で一人で勉強するよりはと通信制の高校をすすめた。”,  I highly suspect there is a common omission, which is 思って or 言って.  Inserting this missing block back to the sentence, I believe everything is becoming as clear as daylight.

“家で一人で勉強するよりはと思って、通信制の高校をすすめた。”

Comment: So I'll never be able to find a より to which I won't be able to add a は? And how sure are you about this 思って omission? It does seem to make sense. The question is if it's slangish or a grammatically correct omission?

Comment: Check this out
https://hinative.com/ja/questions/1514703

Comment: If the above link does not work, you may google the following phrase

就職浪人するよりはと思って、 大学院に進みました。 その‘よりは‘ はどういう意味ですか?

Comment: It worked (although the rest of the site doesn't). I wonder how often is that と added after よりは, since it wasn't even part of his question. May I ask how would you translated his proposed sentence to English?

Answer (score 1):

文の区切りは｢～するよりは、〇〇とすすめる｣ですね。
ここでの‘’と‘’の使い方ですが、例として｢俺はこの商品が高いと聞いたよ｣
つまり、ここでは｢って聞いたよ｣と同じ使い方ですね。
そんな感じです。

Comment: 「家で一人で勉強するよりはと通信制の高校をすすめた。」と 「家で一人で勉強するよりは通信制の高校とすすめた。」は同じの意味ですか？